# Stuck on GNU GRUB version 2.02 menu

Tags: linux

Stuck at grub 2.02 menu after deleting linux partition from dual boot system on windows without deleting grub partition. Cannot boot from drive. Cannot acces boot menu. Evertime i restart i am on the gnu grub menu

Comment: Try boot-repair-disk ... it will fix the grub menu and then you could possibly fix it from inside windows or keep the (fixed) grub bootloader after the repair. (https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

Comment: I have no way to get repair disk as this is my only computer. I do have linux mint on a bootable flashdrive and that's it

Comment: If linux mint is a live distribution on your flash ... You can search here how to install and run "boot-repair" on it and use it to fix your issue with grub ... if it is not live but installed in there ... the same way will work ... if it is just an installation disk/usb ... I am sorry, but possibly you have to find at least a live cd/dvd/usb